# Solving periodic ODE with finite difference having strange results...

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I was wondering if you could help me understand.

I am trying to solve this eigenvalue problem numerically via finite difference (I've solved it already using a spectral method).

\begin{equation}
i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \lambda u
\end{equation} with boundary conditions $u(0) = u(1)$.

I've used the following discretisation of the operator on the left-hand-side
\begin{equation}
\frac{u_n - u_{n-1}}{\Delta x}  
\end{equation} and with this, I simply use eig (in python) on the following matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 &... & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 &... & 0 \\ \vdots  &  & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ \vdots  &  & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ 1 &  & 0  & 0  & -1 \\  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}, but this way I find that the xvalues are not prescribed and it gives me eigenvalues in a circle (they should be real). I don't even know what part of maths this is... Help please!

Kindest regards,

Catherine

Answer (score 2):

So you get $$u_n=(1-iλΔx)^{-n}u_0,$$ and if periodicity means $u_N=u_0$, then $(1-iλΔx)^N=1$. This has solutions $$1-iλΔx=e^{iα}=\cos(α)+i\sin(α)$$ with $αN=k2\pi\iff α=2k\pi\frac{Δx}{L}$. Or
$$
λ=\frac{1-e^{iα}}{iΔx}\approx \frac{2k\pi}{L}
$$
the last for small values of $k$.

Yes, the eigenvalues lie on a large circle (very large for larger $N$), but the smaller eigenvalues lie close to the real axis.

---

If you want real eigenvalues, use the more symmetric trapezoidal discretization
$$
i\frac{u_n-u_{n-1}}{Δx}=λ\frac{u_n+u_{n-1}}{2}.
$$